# ContractNotFound: No contract deployed at 0x6

Tags: solidity, ganache

I restarted Ganache, and then when I ran the [brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network ganache-local] again, I got an error. However, it was a success before restarting.

How can I fix this error?

[image]

I tried deleting the old network and rebuilding a new one, but it didn't work.

```
from operator import network, config
from brownie import FundMe, MockV3Aggregator, network, config
from scripts.helpful_scripts import (
    get_account,
    deploy_mocks,
    LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS,
)


def deploy_fund_me():
    account = get_account()
    if network.show_active() not in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        price_feed_address = config["networks"].[network.show_active()][
            "eth_usd_price_feed"
        ]
    else:
        deploy_mocks()
        price_feed_address = MockV3Aggregator[-1].address

    fund_me = FundMe.deploy(
        price_feed_address,
        {"from": account},
        publish_source=config["networks"].[network.show_active()].get("verify"),
    )
    print(f"Contract deployed to {fund_me.address}")


def main():
    deploy_fund_me()
```

**Ganache --->>> ganache-local**

[image]

**My project**

[image]

Comment: can you share your deploy script?

Comment: sure, I've re-edited my question, but I think the code is fine because it worked fine until I restarted ganache.

Comment: I found a similar question, however, I don't want to change to Development, so how can I solve my problem?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239681/18203653

Comment: IDK brownie but in truffle you need to specify network specs. Find a config file in your project and modify the network properties according to your Ganache network settings.

Comment: During the contract creation process, the configuration of Ganache is shown in the figure. And there is no hash code address in my configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally, I delete the build folder and re-compile-->> "brownie compile". The issue was done~

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).